# BOOL properties naming in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, properties, boolean, naming-conventions

I'm not a native speaker so I'm a little bit confused in the following situation. There are well known [Apple naming conventions on accessor methods](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/Articles/NamingMethods.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001282-1004202-BCIGGFCC). But they cover only simple cases.

Let's say I have a `Fetcher` class, which obviously can `-fetch`. I would like to be able to perform a delayed fetch, and check if it was scheduled correctly. Unfortunately both words (fetch and schedule) could be nouns or verbs. What names should I choose?

1. `-scheduleFetch` vs. `-scheduleFetching` for the method which schedules?
2. - `@property (readonly, getter=isFetchScheduled) BOOL fetchScheduled` vs
   - `@property (readonly) BOOL fetchIsScheduled` vs
   - `getter=hasScheduledFetch` vs
   - anything else?

   (all these break "Don’t twist a verb into an adjective by using a participle" convention from the docs)

It gets even worse, because I have a `Request` property in this `Fetcher`, and this request has `@property (getter=isTyped) BOOL typed`. How should I name a wrapper property for the latter one? Same variants as above: `hasTypedRequest`, `isRequestTyped`, `requestIsTyped`, or anything else?

Answer (score 2):

The most important rule from my understanding is readability and consistency. I would use "scheduleFetch", "isFetchScheduled", and "isRequestTyped". If you have other conventions in your program, however, stick to those.

To assist in understanding, because fetch and schedule can both be verbs and nouns, it is okay to leave them both ambiguous.

As far as the don't twist with participle idea, I personally don't worry about that too much if it makes me strain to come up with weird english phrases.